# In puppeteer how to access exports from a script injected using 'page.addScriptTag'?

Tags: puppeteer

In a puppeteer script I want to inject some utility functions to a webpage via `page.addScriptTag` and use some exports defined in the file.

```
  await page.addScriptTag({path: './utils/browser.js', type: 'module'})
  await page.evaluate(() => {
    // how do I do `import { foo } from './utils/browser.js'` here?
  })
```

The injected file looks like this:

```
export function foo() {}
```

I'm using '"type": "module"' in my package.json if this is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

You can try dynamic `import()` with ['data:' URLs](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_data_imports):

```js
  await page.evaluate(async (source) => {
    const { foo } = await import(`data:text/javascript,${source}`);
  }, fs.readFileSync('./utils/browser.js', 'utf8'));
```

Comment: Yes, using import in the function is another issue. Dynamic import would try to load the file relative to the domain of the page in browser, not relative to my project. I guess the only option is to add `window.foo = foo`  in the imported file and use them as globals in the `evaluate` callback.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand you need a local module. You can try  'data:' URLs — see the edited answer.

Comment: However, I do not know what the limit is for the length of the transferred arguments.